# Pylint complaining about function reports

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7, pylint

I am attempting to import functions from couple of files called

```
mysql_calls.py

system_calls.py
```

If I import with

```
from mysql_calls import *
```

pylint complains about wildcard import and if I just do

```
import mysql_calls
```

`pylint` complains about undefined vars when I use functions from imported modules.

> alert_feeder.py:215:17: E0602: Undefined variable 'mysql_query'
>   (undefined-variable)

What is the right way to do this? I am also not (yet?) using every functions from imported modules, and `pylint` also complains about that.

Comment: `import mysql_calls` then use `mysql_calls.mysql_query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `import mysql_calls`, its function `mysql_query` is accessible as `mysql_calls.mysql_query`.

More details: [Modules - Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. My score went from like 1.5 to 8.95